# Getting the data from a foreign key table

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, php

I have a table that relates a user to client using both their table id's

UsersClients Table

```
   ---------------------
   | userid | clientid |
   ---------------------
   | 2      | 32       |
   | 3      | 43       |
   | 2      | 24       |
   | 2      | 12       |
   ---------------------
```

The userid relates to the id field with in my Users Table
The clientid relates to the id field with in my Clients Table

I have linked them all up OK.

My question is how can I use this key table to get the details.  For instance, I am the user with an ID of 2. By simply doing a query on the above UsersClients Table with the userid of 2, I will simply get the following results 32,24,12.

Now, in order to get the then client details from clients table for each of the returned results, I would query the clients db with something like

```
   SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE id IN(32,24,12);
```

But as I have the above UsersClients Table linking up to the relevant tables that I can approach this better, so I don't have to first scrape the UsersClients Table for each client ID then scrape the clients table for the relevant details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple JOIN query would be in order

```
SELECT B.* FROM UsersClients A
INNER JOIN Clients B ON A.clientid = B.id
WHERE A.userid = 2;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: it seems not to throw error but yet it does not seem to display any data either. even with specifying a field etc. Many Thanks for the reply

Comment: Changed the JOIN syntax because there is no clientid in the Clients tables. Please try again...

Comment: yup that worked thought it might be something like that i change everything except the clientid much appreciated